# Activate the Speech to Text on UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview

When the keyboard appears for UITextViews and UITextFields there is a microphone button that lets you do Speech to Text. Is there anyway for me to activate this functionality without having the user to click on the button?

Comment: Not sure if any public APIs exist for that. Maybe you can find something interesting using `class-dump`. Dirty hackish solution in case you don't: simulate a click using `UITouch`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no public API to access that feature.  You can do this using third party libraries like Nuance or OpenEars.

Comment: Yea I do have OpenEars implemented, but since it's offline translation it can only do a small vocabulary accurately. So I was hoping to be able to use Apple's online translation for free. I believe Nuance cost money to use their server translation.